# Xamarin app crashes in iOS 10.3 but working in version above 11

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

i have a xamarin app which is working in iOS version of 11.0 and above but it always fail when i set simulator version to 10 or lower when checking build logs they are same except in case of lower versions log has this line

```
Xamarin.Hosting: Simulated process has exited. process with id 7642 not found
```

now i don't understand why this process exits 
can this be because of some nuget package that is not supporting the platform ?

Note:-MinimumOSVersion set in info.plist file is 10.0 and issue is coming in 10.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/4741

Xcode 10's release notes:

> Weak linking against frameworks that are not present in simulator
>   runtimes older than iOS 12.0, tvOS 12.0, and watchOS 5.0 yet are
>   present in macOS Mojave can cause an app to crash on launch when
>   running in those older simulator runtimes. (41224059) Workaround: Use
>   older simulator runtimes on macOS High Sierra

Comment: Hi According to this link issue is only there in Simulators but i my case same issue is occuring in physical devices too.

Comment: Then you are using some API that is not supported on iOS 10. Possibly some nuget package may require higher version too.

Comment: is there a way or logging that i can know which package that is?